# Custom Processor NiFi: How to use session.read with a long running external process

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am trying to make a custom processor that read a FlowFile as input and call an external process (as `ExecuteStreamCommand` does), but I would like to make a batch duration time that after that amount will be sent out the results as a new flowfiles (as `ExecuteProcess` does).

So I am trying make a mix of these two processors, but I am stuck, because I cannot properly get the grip of `session.read()` combined with `getInputStream()`.

Here's what I did with my `NewProcessor.java` file: 
- At the beginning of `onTrigger` I get the flow file session with

```
FlowFile inputFlowFile = session.get();
        if (null == inputFlowFile) {
            return;
        }
```

- Then I create a new Flowfile having as parent the incoming flowfile:

  FlowFile flowFile = session.create(inputFlowFile);
- I use the [`launchProcess`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/c15876494a7fb9ea5eb6cacf02a6ee5f46faa333/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ExecuteProcess.java#L317) function taken from the `ExecuteProcess` in order to run the external process wrapped in a `Future` so I can call it after the `Batch` period
- Here is where it gets tricky to me - I would need a `session.read` to read from InputFlowfile as `ExecuteStreamCommand` does [here](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/c15876494a7fb9ea5eb6cacf02a6ee5f46faa333/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ExecuteStreamCommand.java#L486) in a [`InputStreamCallback`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/c15876494a7fb9ea5eb6cacf02a6ee5f46faa333/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ExecuteStreamCommand.java#L546-L617) . But since it is tightly linked with the `session.write()` I don't know how to correctly separate them to make my external process read from the incoming flowfile.

Can Someone give me some hint?

Comment: you could have two sessions - one for reading, another for writing. and time to time when you want to send written files - commit writing session, and create a new one to write next files...

Comment: This is what I had in mind but I don't know how to read from flowfile and pass as input to the external process :/

Comment: session.read(ff) returns input stream and not linked to writing so, you could redirect this stream where you need . https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.java#L583